# How to parse a UTC epoch 1352716800 to NSDate?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, utc

I'm reading data from a XML file which has a UTC date looking like "2011-05-04T00:00:00", and a UTC epoch looking like 1352716800.

Parsing the UTC epoch to NSDate would probably be much safer than messing around with a complex date format. How would I parse the UTC epoch to NSDate? With NSDateFormatter and a special format for "UTC Epoch"?

I think that it is `[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:epoch]` and a test seemed to work. But I am not sure if that's just correct by accident or if the "UTC epoch" is "Since 1970". The Apple Docs don't mention UTC Epoch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YES,  you are correct it is UTC Epoch. For Reference if "Epoch time is UTC" checkout [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

```
NSString *epochTime = @"1352716800";

// (Step 1) Convert epoch time to SECONDS since 1970
NSTimeInterval seconds = [epochTime doubleValue];
NSLog (@"Epoch time %@ equates to %qi seconds since 1970", epochTime, (long long) seconds);

// (Step 2) Create NSDate object
NSDate *epochNSDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
NSLog (@"Epoch time %@ equates to UTC %@", epochTime, epochNSDate);
```

Comment: The division by 1000 is incorrect. UTC epoch is in seconds, not in milliseconds. And so is most likely the number 1352716800.

Comment: If you are getting the epoch time from an external service like an API, double check with the source if they send it on seconds or milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to *parse* the UTC epoch date. Instead you can more or less directly create an `NSDate` instance from it:

```
long utcEpoch = 1352716800;
NSDate* date = [Date dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: utcEpoch];
```

Comment: Except that NSTimeInterval is double, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's double. But it will be automatically converted.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the timestamp retrieved from Firebase (`kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp`), the epoch is expressed in milliseconds:

> A placeholder value for auto-populating the current timestamp (time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds) by the Firebase servers.

In that case dividing by 1000 is needed if you use `initWithTimeIntervalSince1970` in iOS.